# Finding out the period of function $f(x+2)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$

Tags: functions

Let a real valued function $f(x)$ has the property $$f(x+2)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$$ The question is to find out period of $f(x)$

I tried to subsitute $\frac{f(x-2)-5}{f(x-2)-3}$ in place of $f(x)$ in the given equation and ended up getting $$\frac{2f(x-2)-5}{f(x-2)-2}=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$$
I couldnot proceed after this.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Take $f(0)=a$, say, and iterate.  What are $f(2), f(4), etc. ?$

Comment: "ended up getting ..."; the very first $2$ in the numerator should not be there.

Comment: @JohnHughes I couldnot get what you mean?I have rechecked and I think there is no problem of $2$ in the numerator

Answer (score 1):

The period is 8.

Steps:

1. Express f(x+4) in terms of f(x+2) by replacing x with x+2
2. Using the given equation, express f(x+4) in terms of f(x)
3. Express f(x+6) in terms of f(x+4)
4. Using the equation obtained in 2, express f(x+6) in terms of f(x)
5. Express f(x+8) in terms of f(x+6)
6. Using the equation obtained in 4, express f(x+8) in terms of f(x), and that should do the trick.